# Updating label in a cell of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

My `UITableViewCell` has a cell template which is created from another nib file. The cell has a `UIlabel` object. Now, once the `UITableView` has loaded and the text has been displayed, and if I want to change its value by clicking a button from another cell, How should I do it ?

I have updated the text of the `UIlabel` but how to show it on the screen? Should I reload the entire table? Kindly let me know if there is any good way to do it.

Comment: If you have an array for label just change the array object and reload the tableview  with reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Comment: Yes you should reload the table by calling `reloadData`

Answer (score 0):

You can use KVO for this purpose. Each cell observes the model, and when it changes, update some fields.